# Cannot make table re-order to work

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

From the UITableViewCell showsReorderControl docs:

```
For the reordering control to appear, you must not only set this property but implement the UITableViewDataSource method tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:. In addition, if the data source implements tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath: to return NO, the reordering control does not appear in that designated row.
```

I've got the both in my tableviewController :

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    NSLog(@"move from:%d to:%d", fromIndexPath.row, toIndexPath.row);
   //just for test
}
```

My cell properties including re-order controls :

[image]

And yet I can't see the re-order control, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you put your UITableView into editing mode via

```
[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

?

The first method you posted is needless, by the way, as that is the default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to actually get into edit mode for the table. Either try it in code when your view appears or create a button that will do it.

```
[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```